# SCHEME - printf as a debug technique?

Tags: debugging, scheme, printf

Is the printf command a sensible way to attempt a debug or other techinuqes would be faster and/or more precise?

(Assume that I'm using Racket or other dialects that allow printf).

Comment: Racket has a pretty decent debugger, so I guess that would be preferred over logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off. Scheme (R7RS, R6RS, R5RS) doesn't have `printf`. There is `display` and [SRFI-28](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-28/srfi-28.html) `format`. Because of this I'll just read `printf` as print statement which again could mean you're just using `display`.

The correct answer is that your code should be made into small procedures that can be unit tested easily. If you do that you'll never need either a debugger or printing out debug info ever again.

Usually Scheme uses expressions and it's not always easy to just add a print statement without having to wrap it and the following statement in a `begin`. Because of that you may introduce bugs when you add and, even worse, remove debug information from your code. eg.

```
(if (test arg)
    (call-something (car arg))
    (call-something-else (cdr arg))
```

So how much would you have to change in order to print the result of `(test arg)` without altering the course of the code and how easy would it be to remove that without introducing a new bug? If I really wanted to print out debug info I would have made a macro:

```
(define-syntax dbg
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ . rest) 
     (let ((expr 'rest)
           (res rest))
       (display (list expr '=> res))
       res))))
```

Now you could just prefix `dbg` where you want to inspect:

```
(if (dbg test arg)
    (call-something (car arg))
    (call-something-else (cdr arg))
```

Imagine that the result og `(test arg)` is `5`, then you'll get `((test arg) => 5)` out without altering the result to `if`.

If you happen to use DrRacket it's very simple to use the very good debugger and macro stepper which they have. With it you'll just set a break point and run towards the interesting parts and step through as you see the values every step calculates. There are probably some other IDEs as well but I stopped looking after I found racket. Even when using DrRacket nothing is keeping you from using a different implementation in production, like Ikarus, provided that you write in one of the Scheme reports and not something implementation specific.

Be careful! People who are too comfortable with debuggers tend to make long procedures that look more like FORTRAN than Scheme. The best is to write programs as if you didn't have any means of debugging, use the debugger when you feel the need and refactor your code if you find yourself in the debugger all the time.